# Semicharacters of $\mathbb{R}_+$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, semigroups

I'm looking for a reference on the semicharacters of the semigroup $\mathbb{R}_+$ (and possibly also $\mathbb{R}^n_+$). It would be great if it contained a proof of what do the semicharacters look like in these two cases.

Does anyone know of such reference?

Comment: You take it as an additive semigroup, I take it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You should assume continuity. Without this assumption there is no good answer. With this assumption, they are all linear. This was asked on MSE many times.